# Providing context in "dummydata/context" doesn't work

Tags: qml, qt-creator, qt-designer

A component often uses some context properties (eg parent.width) and hence, when designing this component in Qt Quick Designer, it is useful to somehow provide this context.

The Qt Quick Designer documentation [states](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-using-qt-quick-designer.html#loading-placeholder-data) that it should be possible to provide this parent context object in the `dummydata/context` directory.

However, I don't get it working

I have a `main.qml`  file containing

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width:parent.width
    height:parent.height
    color: "green"
}
```

and I have a `dummydata/context/main.qml` file containing

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import QmlDesigner 1.0

DummyContextObject {
    parent: Item {
        width: 640
        height: 300
    }
}
```

However, when opening `main.qml` in Designer, it still gets `width=height=0`.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: @Fabian Not yet: I also entered it as an issue in Qt https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15530 There is some feedback there but I haven't been able to look into it yet.